# header location php issues

Tags: php

Here's my code, that works on localhost and redirect me to the login page:

```
require("common.php"); 

unset($_SESSION['user']); 
 session_destroy(); 

header("Location: login.php");
```

But when I upload it to my web server, the header is not sent. User is not redirected to my login page when he logs in. But the session was already started.

Here's the code:

```
require("common.php"); 


$submitted_username = ''; 


if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 


    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 


    $login_ok = false; 


    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

    if($check_password === $row['password'])
        { 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
      if($login_ok) 
    { 

        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 


        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

     header("Location:form_menu.php"); 

    } 
    else 
    { 

        echo("<font color=red>Login Failed. Icorrect Password </font>"); 


        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    }

    }
}
```

How to resolve this problem? Is there a problem with my web server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114039/php-headerlocation-inside-a-function-redirects-without-calling-function

Comment: @Jerome, always use `exit;` after `header(); and http URL instead of relative path.`

Comment: You should call session_start() before manipulating the session. You can do it at the top of common.php.

Comment: @Anton, probably, he starts session in common.php

Comment: Good catch! For some reason I thought this was common.php up there without it...

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to session_destroy() but you have no session_start() in your code unless it's in your common.php. And I always make sure I exit; after a header("Location: xxx.php");

So try this, change this:

```
<?php 

require("common.php"); 

unset($_SESSION['user']); 
 session_destroy(); 

header("Location: login.php"); 


?>
```

to this:

```
<?php 
 session_start();

   require("common.php"); 

    unset($_SESSION['user']); 
    session_destroy(); 

    header("Location: login.php"); 
    exit;


?>
```

And then add this to the top of your other code just after the opening

```
session_start();
```

Comment: @MrTechieless, probably, he starts session in common.php

Answer (score 1):

At the top of page add

```
     ob_start();
```

And the Bottom of Page add

```
    ob_end_flush();
```

I hope it will work.

A `header` in PHP always run before any output occurs, so turn on output buffering.